# SerialPort data in Hexadecimal

Tags: qt, c++11

I would like to extract the data from a sensor in hexadecimal (These are provided in Hexadecimal)

I used this code, but the result displayed is 0.

Is this the right way to receive data in hexadecimal? Is it necessary to pass first in QByteArray

Thank you

```
Imu::Imu() :
    moving(false)
{

    serialPort = new QSerialPort("COM3",this);

    if (!serialPort->open( QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        log_warning("imu","failed to open device file \"%s\", IMU measures will be unavailable",qPrintable(serialPort->portName()));
        return;
    }

    if (!serialPort->setBaudRate(9600))
        log_error("imu","failed to set baudrate, error no %d",serialPort->error());
    serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop); // One Stop bit
    serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);


    pollingTimer = new QTimer(this);
    QObject::connect(pollingTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(pollSerialPort()));
   // QObject::connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &Imu::pollSerialPort);
    QObject::connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::errorOccurred, this, &Imu::handleError);
    pollingTimer->start(10);

    }

Imu::~Imu()
{
   serialPort->close();
}

void Imu::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
{
    if (error == QSerialPort::ResourceError) {
   // qDebug()<<"handleerror" <<;
    }
}

void Imu::pollSerialPort()
{
    static const unsigned char START_BYTES[2] = {0x55,0xAA};
    static const QByteArray START_WORD((char*)START_BYTES,2);
    static QTime startTime = QTime::currentTime();
    if (!pollingTimer->isActive()){
            pollingTimer->start(10);
    }
    static QByteArray data;
    data.append(serialPort->readAll());
    qDebug() << data.count() << data.toHex();
```

Comment: But why are you sure that after 10 milliseconds after you have opened a port there is a data to read? Why don't you use `waitForReadyRead` method to wait for data available or connect to `readyRead()` signal and read available data in a slot?

Comment: Do all off `serialPort->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    serialPort->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    serialPort->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop); // One Stop bit
    serialPort->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);` return `true`?
Uncomment `// qDebug()<<"handleerror" <<;` in `void Imu::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)`  write it as `qDebug() << error;` to track errors.
Check official examples and follow thier guides https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtserialport-examples.html